# JavaScript - How to create reusable function for REST API requests?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, api, frontend

I'm trying to create some **UI dashboard** for the web services status in my work, but I have no idea how to reuse my code for I could **reuse** my requests for couple of hosts and to split the response for to get the relevant "*led icon*".

The rational is to click on some HTML button and send a couple of **REST API** request in one shot.
Over the response I had an IF statement to pick the relevant LED icon and present it beside the service name inside HTML dashboard.

[image]

My code works fine but IDK how to make it reusable.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var ledTypes = {
    green: "<img src='green.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    red: "<img src='red.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    yellow: "<img src='yellow.png' height='30' width='30'>"
  };

function kongChecking() {
    //Kong - APIs services
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://blablabla.com:1111/bla1", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    console.log(xhttp.status);
}


function ledResponseK() {
    if (xhttp.status === 200 || 204) {
        document.write(ledTypes.green);
    }
    else if (xhttp.status === 500 || 404) {
        document.write(ledTypes.red);
    }
    else if (xhttp.status === 300 || 301 || 302) {
        document.write(ledTypes.yellow);
    }
};
```

The HTML element that send all the REST API requests in one shot -

```
<a href="#tabs-2" onclick="kongChecking()" >Services status</a>
```

The rendered response icon beside the relevant web service -

```
<script>ledResponse()</script><p align="center">Kong API's</p>
```

Comment: I didn't really get what you would like to achieve. Could you explain it again a bit better please?

Comment: I am pretty sure It would be better if you used JS. What I mean, click in HTML works but the better way is to use an eventlistener, you write the response in HTML incorrectly. You should use innerHtml or something else. At last but not least leadResponseK function should be called every time you send the request. It's pretty much to do here.

Comment: When clicking on the HTML button I want it send a multiple GET requests for a different servers and receive a separated response from each server and each web service and present the response by an image (LED icon) beside his web service name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic reuse of this function, only for this specific need can be done like this -

Calling a common function, with array of hosts, and dealing with each response with the same function:

```js
var hosts = ['https://www.url1.com', 'https://www.url2.com', 'https://www.url3.com']; //Added

var ledTypes = {
  green: "<img src='green.png' height='30' width='30'>",
  red: "<img src='red.png' height='30' width='30'>",
  yellow: "<img src='yellow.png' height='30' width='30'>"
};

function kongChecking() {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //Kong - APIs services
  for (var hostIndx = 0; hostIndx < hosts.length; hostIndx++) {
    try {
      xhttp.open("GET", hosts[hostIndx], false);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      xhttp.send();
      var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      console.log(xhttp.status);
      //Handle response: (passing the current host first child - span element
      handleLedResponse(xhttp.status, hostIndx);
    } catch (err) {
      handleLedResponse(500, hostIndx);
    }
  }
}


function handleLedResponse(response, hostIndx) {
  var curSpan = document.getElementById('host_' + hostIndx);
  //Better switch this ugly nested if's to SWITCH / CASE
  if (response === 200 || 204) {
    curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.green;
  } else if (response === 500 || 404) {
    curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.red;
  } else if (response === 300 || 301 || 302) {
    curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.yellow;
  }
};
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#tabs-1" onclick="kongChecking()">Check all status</a>
<br/>
<div>Host 1 Status <span id='host_0'></span></div>
<div>Host 2 Status <span id='host_1'></span></div>
<div>Host 3 Status <span id='host_2'></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems the way i looking for. but how i call to kongChecking function through the HTML and triggering the relevant host? can you please publish the example for this?

Comment: Do you want one button that checks all, or one per host? @IdanE

Comment: I want to click on HTNL button by "onClick" and send this request for all the hosts in one and to present their responses in separated

Comment: Actually IDK to use the innerHTML you meant in your answer above. can you please add example for this?

Comment: Thanks Ziv, we are almost there :)
I can't managed to send the request for the customized host by the ID.. it always sent to host "0".
and I've received the error below on the console log - 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
&nbsp;/repos/dashboard/kongReq.js:35

Comment: @IdanE can you show what you have tried?  check if your for loop is good, what is the variable you use for the loop?

Comment: It works ok now.. thanks!
but there's exception regarding the InnerHTML on the console log..

Comment: @IdanE did you add the span's with the ID = host_X ?

Comment: Yes I did.. actually I've add id='host_0' but it receive state of another host because this web service is stopped on host=0 and the led icon is green

Comment: Probably I've found the reason for this problem. when it sent the REST request it receives 2 responses. one with "OPTIONS" type and the second one is the expected one of GET type

Comment: I'm less familiar with XHTTP so i can't help much further, you also need to check if it has callback function, because its probably runs async, causing strange things when passing params without the callback method. If you still have issues i suggest posting a new question with the new code and the problem. @IdanE G/L

Comment: You're right, it's a definantly another issue and I'll investigate it.